# How to replace src with regular expression and jquery

Tags: regex

I have the following output.

```
<img width='70' height='70' class='centreimg' src="http://localhost/aktivfitness_new/assets/images/centre/centre1.jpg" />
```

There are same outputs with centre2.jpg etc.
Now I want to replace this centre1.jpg to hover.jpg when I hover.

But when I use the following it becomes centre1hover.jpg

```
 $(".centreimg").mouseover(function() {
        var hoverimg = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "hover.jpg";
        ...
```

Something is wrong with match(/[^.]+/) + "hover.jpg part.
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think this would be easier:

```
var newSrc = oldSrc.replace(/[^\/\.]+\./, 'hover.');
```

Anyway: you shouldn't use Javascript for hovers =) If there is another way: use it. Not only is it a bad practice, it's also not user friendly: when the image loads when you hover, the user will see a 'flash' because the entire image still has to be loaded = not pretty.